# Fpdf - set background color for row

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I need set lightgrey background color for row. I use multicell view for my PDF. 
My code is:

```
      $countRow = 0;
        foreach ($arrPeriod as $key=>$val) {
            if($countRow % 2 == 0){
                $this->setFillColor(230,230,230);
                $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
            }else{
                $this->setFillColor(255,255,255);
                $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
            }
            $this->Row([
                     $val['lead_name'],
                     $val['content'],
                     $val['date_due']
                ]
            );
            $countRow++;
        }
```

I have problem that not full column has lightgrey background:

[image]

My Row function is:

```
function Row($data)
{
    //Calculate the height of the row
    $nb = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $nb = max($nb,$this->GetMultiCellHeight($this->widths[$i], $data[$i]));
    }
    $h = 5 * $nb;
    //Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Draw the cells of the row
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $w = $this->widths[$i];
        $a = isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        //Save the current position
        $x = $this->GetX();
        $y = $this->GetY();
        //Draw the border
        $this->Rect($x, $y, $w, $h);
        //Set font
        if ($i == 0 || $i == 2) {
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
        } else {
            $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
        }
        //Print the text
        $this->MultiCell($w, 4.5, $data[$i], 0, $a, true);
        //Put the position to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x + $w, $y);
    }
    //Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);
}
```

How can I fix it and fill correct my row?

Comment: Pass a flag to your `row` function to indicate whether or not you want the gray background. Right now you are setting the color before the size of the cell is known. Set both the text and fill colors within your function after you've sized the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You already calculate the maximum number of cells/height in a column per row (`$nb` / `$h`).

So just draw the background in your `Rect()` call instead of the `MulitCell()`:

```
$this->Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, true);
```

In any case you should check the caluclation, too: You calculate the height by `5 * $nb` but the cell height in your `MultiCell()` call is only `4.5`. This will shift of when you have more lines.